# Playing sounds as Android Service with Delphi FMX

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Have a project which accumulates data from a 3 Party Device to android Tablets / Phones
this is set to beep when a data packet is accepted and works fine until the App goes to the background

I thought that if I Created a service to make the sound this would be over come however I have found that I cant Address the FMX components from the Service so the present way that I am implementing the sound is not available

in the main app I Used

```
   procedure PlayMedia(aFile: String);
   var
   l_mp: TMediaPlayer;
   begin
   l_mp := TMediaPlayer.Create(Application);
   l_mp.FileName := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath, aFile);
 
   l_mp.Play;

   end;
```

In the Service I Tried

```
procedure TDMSounds.PlaySound(afile: String);
var
  Volume: Integer;
  StreamType: Integer;
  ToneType: Integer;
  ToneGenerator: JToneGenerator;
  RingToneMgr:JRingToneManager;
  RingTone:JRingtone;
begin

  Volume := TJToneGenerator.JavaClass.MAX_VOLUME;

  StreamType := TJAudioManager.JavaClass.STREAM_SYSTEM;
  ToneType := TJToneGenerator.JavaClass.TONE_DTMF_9;

  ToneGenerator := TJToneGenerator.JavaClass.init(StreamType, Volume);
  ToneGenerator.startTone(ToneType, 1000);

end;
```

carn't seem to get a result from the service

any Ideas Greatly Appreciated

Comment: Does the code you presented that you're using in a service work in an application?

Comment: Why don't you create a notification when the task is complete instead of playing sound. This way you allow your users to control whether they want to be notified only visually or also auditorily. This is the main purpose of Notification system.

Comment: Thank You SilverWarior followed Your suggestion and now have a very acceptable solution